# windows cmd batch file calculations

Tags: windows, batch-file

The output of the code below just repeats "Unbalanced parentheses"x100. If I take out the parentheses and leave %%i%5 it just loops numbers 1-100 without the mod. If I make it add or subtract, it works fine. Why won't it find the mod, specifically?

```
    :MAIN
     setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
     set result=0
     for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do (
     set /a result= (%%i%5)
     echo !result!
     )
     endlocal
```

I have this other bit of code with a problem I can't seem to find. If nonzero numbers are entered, it works just fine.

```
@echo off

:MAIN
set /p number1= "Enter 1st number:”
if %number1%== "9" goto second_num

:second_num
set /p number2= “Enter 2nd number:”
if %number2%== “0” goto error
if %number2%== "9" goto division

:division
set /a result= (%number1%/%number2%)
echo %result%
pause
exit

:error
echo "Error. Cannot divide by 0. Start over."
goto MAIN
```

But if the second number is 0, it's output is:

```
Divide by zero error.
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue...
```

And when I press a key, the program ends instead of going to :error. I realize there's a problem with an if statement. And why does it say ECHO is off? Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 set /a result= (%%i%5)
```

is your problem. The closing parenthesis is seen by the FOR as  *its* closing parenthesis, so the SET has unbalanced parentheses.

Change the `)` in the `SET` to `^)` - the caret (`^`) escapes the `)` telling the processor that it's part of the `set`, not of the `for`

While you're at it, the `%5` should be `%%5` becaue bizarrely, `%` escapes `%`, not `^` and the processor needs to be told that the `%` isn't part of `%5` - the fifth parameter to the batchfile.

The next problem is caused by not understanding that an environment variable is **ALWAYS** a string. The only time quotes are needed is when it may contain certain characters like SPACES. The statement `if %var%==7` is comparing the string `contents of var` with the string `7`, hence your statements are comparing `the contents of the variable` with `"9"` (or whatever). These are **NEVER** going to be equal. Now - `"%number2%"` may be equal, as both of the actual STRINGS may be equal.

If `ECHO` has nothing as its "argument" then it reports its state, that is either ON or OFF. SInce `RESULT` was not SET because of the error attempting to divide by 0, the statement boils down to `ECHO` so the echo state is duly reported.

The cure is to try `ECHO.` - the dot gives `ECHO` something to chew on and ot'll produce a blank line since %result% is set to [nothing]

Comment: This worked very well! Thanks for explaining everything very clearly!